# XNA Skinning Sample - exporting from Blender recognize only first animation clip

Tags: xna, c#, animation, blender, skinning

**(and sorry for my English)**
I'm using animation components from XNA Skinning Sample. It works great but when I export a model from Blender, it does not recognize any other animation clips than the first one. So I have three animation clips, but XNA recognize only one. Also, when I looked up on Xml file of the model in Debug\Content\obj directory, there is only one animation clip, but when I check code directly from .fbx file, it seems to be alright.

Link to my model files:
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=8480AF53198F0CF3!139

BIG Thanks in forward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because XNA 4.0 does not support more than one take per fbx file, the simplest solution is to export the model and armature first, then export one animation at a time with only the armature per fbx and merge the result in the content pipeline. [Shawn Hargreaves did a post on this with code.](https://shawnhargreaves.com/blog/merging-animation-files.html)

Comment: Thanks for advice, I didn't know that. I found even another solution, if I download Windows Phone SDK 7.1, I'll get an update for XNA which supports more takes. But it include some bug, that every take has the same count of frames as the first one.